# Is the Gorillapod sturdy enough for super-zoom lens and long exposure?

Tags: lens, dslr, long-exposure, superzoom, gorillapod

I am interested in buying the Gorillapod SLR-Zoom to be used as a travel tripod. My camera is a D3300 together with a 35mm and a super zoom lens (still haven't decided which one to buy, but something around 18-250mm). In total the maximum camera weight would roughly be around 1kg, so that is good for the SLR-Zoom weight limit.

My doubts however, are whether the Gorillapod is sturdy enough for long exposure shots (5-30seconds), and also, will I struggle with the center of gravity if I have a long zoom lens attached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. While a Gorillapod is highly practical, and I have the SLR-Zoom too,  it is weakest for long lenses because it is very sensitive to an off-center center-of-gravity. When a lens extends out much from the camera body, Gorillapod becomes unstable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Whats your setup?

Comment: That's a tough question because I own 5 cameras and am constantly rolling through review units! Overall, the Gorillapod works extremely well with Ultra-Zoom Bridge Cameras and Mirrorless with medium-sized lens. For a DSLR, my lenses are mostly too big to get good stability, even with the SLR-Zoom.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't I returned one I'd ordered to use with a Canon EOS 40D. It couldn't support this even with the fairly lightweight 50mm f1.8 lens.

It would be worth investigating the `Gorillapod Focus`, which is designed for heavier cameras. I'm going to get one to try it out, but haven't got round to it yet

Comment: I ended up ordering the focus and the ballhead x from Amazon last night after reading some good reviews, despite being slightly larger and heavier than the SLR-Zoom so I expect to be sturdier too. Will let you know how it goes!

Comment: @rikket I just found this too: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61279/what-is-the-better-material-choice-for-a-gorillapod-metal-or-plastic

Answer (score 0):

I recently picked up an SLR Zoom with the ball head to use with my Canon T5i for taking macro photos outside. It's not perfect, and it can get pretty finicky for stability if you have the camera too much off level.

It's good in a pinch (and infinitely better than hand-holding for macro work), but using either a long timer or a remote becomes critical, and there is a lot of vibration to work with.

That said, you'd likely be better off with the more expensive Gorillapod Focus (a quick check on Amazon shows it's well over twice as much as the SLR Zoom).